# How to run todolist from abstractspoon in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compatibility, wine, time-management

I want to run the [ToDoList](https://web.archive.org/web/20190709033249/http://www.abstractspoon.com:80/tdl_resources.html) (any version from 5.3 to 6.2) in linux (ubuntu 11.04)

```
I've tried to use under wine 1.2 and 1.3 without success:
   1 - I've downloaded the program (todolist_exe.zip);
   2 - unpacked it;
   3 - and use the "Open with Wine Windows Program loader";
   4 - the mouse cursor starts thinking and stops after a few seconds and nothing happens.
```

I've also search the net for help but still haven't found a solution.

After I used the command line "wine ToDoList.exe" it gave me:

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\plugplay.exe"
err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\user_name\\Progs\\todolist\\ToDoList.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\home\\user_name\\Progs\\todolist\\ToDoList.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Please help :)

Comment: Open it up in your terminal, `cd` to that directory, and run `wine todolist_exe.zip`. It gives more verbose output that way. (The WINE people haven't, as far as I know, developed a good logging system yet. Then again, I don't use WINE, so don't quote me on that)

Comment: sorry, I'm just not used to the command line. I've done it now and reedit the question adding the command line error.

Comment: TDL's developer [posted some links](http://abstractspoon.pbworks.com/w/page/1262228/Running%20ToDoList%20on%20Linux%20under%20Wine) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The MFC42u.dll library is a Visual C++ runtime library that does not come by default with WINE.

[winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) should be able to get the script for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks
EXE="winetricks"
chmod +x $EXE
$EXE vcrun2005
$EXE vcrun2008
```

Put the above script somewhere (your home directory, preferably), and make it executable. Run it, and it should be able to get `winetricks` for you, as well as the VC++ runtime redistributable libraries.

Comment: I've run that and it installed, but it didn't fix my problem. The error messages are the same.

Comment: I've also tried to run it from a saved folder in a windows partition (instead of my current of linux) and the result is the same.

Comment: later I've tried to run "winetricks vcrun6" (not shure what it does) that i saw in a forum and finally i was able to run the toDoList.exe using wine (the program must be in a windows partition)

Comment: I tried this.  The program option wizard opened - and then crashed when it was time to load the software

Comment: Installing winetricks and running `winetrucks vcrun6` fixed the  `MFC42u.DLL` error for me too. Note that it requires the `cabextract` package to be installed first. If you don't have it the `winetricks vcrun6` install will fail, and you'll have to delete your `~/.wine` directory before running `winetricks vcrun6` again.

Answer (score 2):

ToDoList will still crash with some big or complicated lists. The following works for me

```
$ winetricks vcrun6 comctl32
```

Comment: works here. got the same error. then i used `winetricks vcrun6 ./ToDoList.exe`. later i was able to use `wine ./ToDoList.exe`